# SQL update based on values in same table

Tags: sql, join, sql-update

I'm trying to put these two queries together, but I'm not sure how.  I'm trying to copy values from within the same budget table from last year's version to this years version, based on them having the same account and workorder.

```
update tablename 
set depreciation = x.depreciation, 
    profile = x.profile, 
    description = x.description 
where version = '2019OP' 
     and account = x.account 
     and workorder = x.workorder

(select * from tablename where version = '2018OP' and batch = '') x
```

I found other questions on this forum similar to this but I couldn't get the answers to work for me.

Thank you

edit - this is SQL server 2012, compatibility level is SQL Server 2008(100)
Using SQL in SSMS

Comment: What RDBMS are you on? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, etc? They all have slightly different syntax for doing this.

Comment: The answers below may or may not work because you failed to specify. Once you let us know which RDBMS you are using then we can upvote and downvote accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
update tablename from tablename
set depreciation = x.depreciation, 
    profile = x.profile, 
    description = x.description 
inner join tablename x on x.version = '2019OP' 
     and tablename.account = x.account 
     and tablename .workorder = x.workorder
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify RDBMS. In Sql Server this should work...

```
UPDATE x1 
SET x1.depreciation = x.depreciation, 
    x1.profile = x.profile, 
    x1.description = x.description 
FROM tablename x1
INNER JOIN tablename x ON x1.account = x.account AND x1.workorder = x.workorder
WHERE x1.version = '2019OP' 
     AND x.version = '2018OP' AND x.batch = ''
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    update tn set tn.depreciation = ly.depreciation, tn.profile = ly.profile, tn.description = ly.description
    FROM tablename  as tn INNER JOIN 
    (
     SELECT 
        account ,
        workorder,
       depreciation,
       profile ,
      description 
     FROM tablename AS  
     where version = '2018OP'  and batch = ''
     ) AS ly  ON ly.account  = tn.account   AND  ly.workorder  = tn.workorder    
     tn.version = '2019OP'
```